# How to set the parameters for tf.train.shuffle_batch for better performance?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The batch data producer is as follows:

```
BATCH_SIZE=512
HEIGHT=128
WIDTH=128
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
        features={  
            'X': tf.FixedLenFeature([HEIGHT, WIDTH, 1], tf.float32),
            'y': tf.FixedLenFeature([48], tf.int64),
        })
    image = tf.cast(features['X'], tf.float32)
    label = tf.cast(features['y'], tf.float32) 

    return image, label

def inputs(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs, shuffle=True):
    if num_epochs==0:
        num_epochs=None
    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, 
                                                        shuffle=shuffle,
                                                        capacity=16*batch_size,
                                                        num_epochs=num_epochs)

        image, label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

        if shuffle:
            images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], 
                                                           batch_size=batch_size, 
                                                           num_threads=4,
                                                           capacity= 32 * batch_size,
                                                           min_after_dequeue= 1 * batch_size)
        else:
            images, sparse_labels = tf.train.batch([image, label], 
                                                   batch_size=batch_size, 
                                                   num_threads=1,
                                                   capacity= 1 * batch_size,
                                                   allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

        return images, sparse_labels
```

The main consumer code is as follows:

```
t0=time.time()
image_val, label_val = sess.run([image_op, label_op]) 
t1=time.time()
_,output_val,loss_val,summary_val=sess.run([optimizer,output,loss,summary_op], feed_dict={image_ph:image_val, label_ph:label_val, phase_train:True})
t2=time.time() 
print(global_step, loss_val, t1-t0, t2-t1)
```

Some partial results are as follows:

```
(1, 4.7936598e+08, 1.6970429420471191, 1.16087007522583)
(2, 4.7492218e+08, 2.3166861534118652, 1.1548128128051758)
(3, 4.8047462e+08, 2.3188629150390625, 1.1514790058135986)
(4, 4.8164006e+08, 2.533250093460083, 1.150022029876709)
(5, 4.9936403e+08, 2.5249040126800537, 1.1556730270385742)
(6, 5.0953357e+08, 2.3015151023864746, 1.1535239219665527)
(7, 4.6024166e+08, 2.1644229888916016, 1.159350872039795)
(8, 4.7846029e+08, 2.4160208702087402, 1.1518781185150146)
```

It is obviously that the time for data loading is much longer than the time for network execution. I've tried some different combination of `capacity`, `num_threads` and `min_after_dequeue`. The CPU usage is always less than `100%` (about `70%~80%`), which indicates that the multi-threading is not launched. Why?

To my understanding, the queue for data prefetching should be always be full so that the training could be faster. But sadly it seems not. If the data prefetching using queue worked well, the CPU usage should be high because it is busy in data prefetching and simultaneously the data is quickly dequeued from the queue then fed into the network for training. It is strange. Is there a bug in the `tf.train.shuffle_batch`? Why isn't the CPU busy of data prefetching?

Comment: ` min_after_dequeue=  4*batch_size`, you may set this parameter larger.

Comment: @IshantMrinal thanks a lot! I'll try that.